# How to grab a value from one xml to another using xslt variable and value of?

Tags: xml, xslt, junit

I have a build.xml file that contains this property:

```
<property name="appbox1URL" value="http://10.xx.xx.xx"/>
```

I then have a junit-noframes.xml where I want to output the above value. However I am not seeing a value outputted, am I doing something incorrect?

```
<xsl:variable name="appbox1URL" select="document('D:\xxx\Trunk\build.xml')"/>

...
<h2>Summary <xsl:value-of select="$appbox1URL" /></h2>
```

Both files are within the same directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$appbox1URL` variable is a reference to the build xml document, and doing `<xsl:value-of select="$appbox1URL" />` will just output any text nodes within that document (of which there are probably none, as all the values are in attributes).

It looks like you probably want to do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="$appbox1URL//property[@name='appbox1URL']/@value" />
```